# How can I store an Expression<T, bool> where T : CustomClass into an Expression<CustomClass, bool> property?

Tags: c#, expression

This question has the same context as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461781/is-there-a-way-declare-a-linq-like-customwhere-method-and-call-it-without-redu). I'm copy-pasting the exposition part because it's relevant for both:

We have a project that uses legacy databases with which EntityFramework does not work.

So we have started building a poor-man EntityFramework, with a base class `CustomBaseTable` from which entity classes derive. Another class, `CustomQueryBuilder`, has methods that build SQL queries : `BuildSelectQuery(CustomBaseTable p_objEntity)` and so on.

Our first version builds queries quite nicely, but we're using rather crude objects that aren't really flexible (details withheld to save space).

I recently realized that using `Expression` objects would be much more efficient and flexible.

So I'd like to add a method to `CustomBaseTable`, that would work more or less like `Where()`:

```
    EntityTable z_objEntity = new EntityTable();
    z_objEntity.CustomWhere(t => t.Field1 == Value1);
    CustomQueryBuilder z_objBuilder = new CustomQueryBuilder(DBTypeEnum.DataBaseType);
    string z_strQuery = z_objBuilder.BuildSelectQuery(z_objEntity);
```

End exposition.

I want `CustomWhere()` to store that expression in a property and use the latter in `BuildSelectQuery(CustomBaseTable p_objEntity)`, to parse it into a keen SQL Where clause. (Of course it'll happen in a separate method that `Update` and `Delete` queries will use too.)

I've written a property in `CustomBaseTable`:

```
        public Expression<Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>> WhereClauseExpression
```

So `CustomWhere()` should do something like

```
        public static void CustomWhere<T>(this T z_objTable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> p_expWhereClause) where T : CustomBaseTable
        {
            z_objTable.WhereClauseExpression = p_expWhereClause;
        }
```

However, `p_expWhereClause`, being a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` object, can't be converted to `Expression<Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>>`.

I've tried creating an `ICustomBaseTable` from which `CustomBaseTable` derives and make `WhereClauseExpression` a `Expression<Func<ICustomBaseTable, bool>>`, with the same results.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378914/store-expressionfunct-bool-where-as-a-class-property), I tried

```
            z_objTable.WhereClauseExpression = LambdaExpression.Lambda<Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>>(p_expWhereClause.Body, p_expWhereClause.Parameters);
```

Again, the conversion failed.

I don't think I can make `WhereClauseExpression` a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` without declaring `T` in `CustomBaseTable<T>`, which I don't want either.

Of course, a workaround is to have a method in `CustomQueryBuilder` that parses the expression into a Where clause, then store the latter in a `WhereClause` `String` property, but I'd rather generate all the SQL code in one go; it strikes me as cleaner.

Is there a way to store that `Expression` into a property, that will work for any derived class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariance and contravariance real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Comment: If all else fails, storing it in `object` and casting it back as necessary always works. This of course requires that you know the *exact type*, and that also provides a clue as to why your attempt will not work: a `Func<T, bool> where T : CustomBaseTable` is just not the same thing at runtime as a `Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>` for a derived `T`. You can turn it into one by inserting a cast *into the expression itself*, but that means 1) building a new delegate/expression based on the existing one and 2) losing the exact type, which may or may not matter.

Comment: @Charlieface: after reading it, I liloed "Expression", "Func", and "covariance" and chanced upon [Variance in Expression<Func<T,bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452614/variance-in-expressionfunct-bool). Which says out loud that covariance is not supported for `Expression` types. At least it wasn't in 2012.

Comment: `Expression` is a class, which can't be variant, so you would need to make an interface for it which is variant

Comment: @Charlieface: I tried that (the sentence starting with "I've tried creating an `ICustomBaseTable`[...]") and it didn't work out either, but maybe I got something wrong.

Comment: And did you make it covariant?

Comment: I don't think I did. But eventually I went a totally different way. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the answer is: I couldn't... but it didn't matter.

As mentioned in the question, I tried

```
        public static void CustomWhere<T>(this T z_objTable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> p_expWhereClause) where T : CustomBaseTable
        {
            z_objTable.WhereClauseExpression = LambdaExpression.Lambda<Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>>(p_expWhereClause.Body, p_expWhereClause.Parameters);
        }
```

It still didn't work because the parameter in `Parameters` was type `T` instead of `CustomBaseTable`.

So after a bit of fiddling, `CustomWhere()` now looks like

```
        public static void CustomWhere<T>(this T z_objTable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> p_expWhereClause) where T : CustomBaseTable
        {
            z_objTable.WhereClauseExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<CustomBaseTable, bool>>(p_expWhereClause.Body, p_expWhereClause.Parameters.Select(p => Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomBaseTable), p.Name)));
        }
```

Not only does the conversion work perfectly, but even better, the `Expression` objects inside `z_objTable.WhereClauseExpression`, starting with `Body`, use `T` objects and not `CustomBaseTable`. What I needed was for the sub-expressions to use `T`, and that's what I got in the end.